# Cannot download azure devops pipeline artifact in the private network

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

- We created an Azure private kube cluster and block all inbound and outbound traffics.
- Open the related network access for url, such as dev.azure.com, 08wvsblobprodsu6weus73.vsblob.vsassets.io, etc ...
- Run command: `azure-pod:/# az pipelines runs artifact download --artifact-name drop --path "/Downloads" --run-id 36312 --project "xxx" --organization "https://dev.azure.com/xxx" --debug`
- It can download the artifact tool, az login, but failed after getting the manifest ID for the artifact, but from the debug and log, we cannot know which url is blocked. :(

Does anyone know the url which az cli requested, so that we can open it for the private cluster?

Thanks a lot!

The error message is here:

```
cli.azext_devops.dev.common.services: received PAT from environment variable
cli.azext_devops.dev.common.services: Creating connection with personal access token.
cli.azext_devops.dev.common.external_tool: Running external command: /root/.azure/azuredevops/cli/tools/artifacttool/ArtifactTool_alpine-x64_0.2.267/artifacttool pipelineartifact download --service https://dev.azure.com/neste --patvar AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_ARTIFACTTOOL_PATVAR --project Azure Cloud Foundation --pipeline-id 36312 --artifact-name drop --path /Users/jordan/Downloads
cli.azext_devops.dev.common.artifacttool: Getting artifact 'drop' from pipeline '36312' from project 'Azure Cloud Foundation' in organization 'https://dev.azure.com/neste'.
cli.azext_devops.dev.common.artifacttool: The manifest ID for artifact 'drop' is '50A3D1FD9711ACC74B393E5CF30735BF5D2763473309DA9611D86E47DE96F54801'.
cli.azext_devops.dev.common.artifacttool: Encountered an unexpected error.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__65_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage message, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync[T](HttpRequestMessage message, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int64 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object userState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int32 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.ConnectAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.CreateDataProviderAsync(String location, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.ResolveLocationDataAsync(Guid locationAreaIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.LocationService.GetLocationDataAsync(Guid locationAreaIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientInstanceAsync(Type managedType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, VssHttpRequestSettings settings, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientServiceImplAsync(Type requestedType, Guid serviceIdentifier, Func`4 getInstanceAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientAsync[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.ExceptionExtensions.ReThrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Content.Common.AsyncHttpRetryHelper`1.InvokeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ArtifactTool.DedupManifestArtifactClientProvider.GetDedupManifestArtifactClientAsync(String serviceUrl, String patVar, ILogger commandBaseLogger, IAppTraceSource tracer, String cacheDirectory, Boolean cacheWriteAllowed, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\src\ArtifactTool\Providers\DedupManifestArtifactClient\DedupManifestArtifactClientProvider.cs:line 56
   at ArtifactTool.Commands.PipelineArtifactDownloadCommand.ExecuteAsync() in D:\a\1\s\src\ArtifactTool\Commands\PipelineArtifacts\PipelineArtifactDownloadCommand.cs:line 46
   at ArtifactTool.Commands.CommandBase.OnExecuteAsync() in D:\a\1\s\src\ArtifactTool\Commands\CommandBase.cs:line 105
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.InvokeAsync(MethodInfo method, Object instance, Object[] arguments) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 77
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.OnExecute(ConventionContext context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 62
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Apply>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\Conventions\ExecuteMethodConvention.cs:line 25
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.<>c__DisplayClass126_0.<OnExecute>b__0() in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.cs:line 505
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.cs:line 611
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute[TApp](CommandLineContext context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 57
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](CommandLineContext context) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 145
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](IConsole console, String[] args) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 130
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](String[] args) in C:\projects\commandlineutils\src\CommandLineUtils\CommandLineApplication.Execute.cs:line 112
```

Comment: In our success result, I found the next step is:

{"@t":"2023-05-04T06:29:14.4033988Z","@m":"ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session d121d6b1-bc24-4c48-b2cb-88c1794abd1e","@i":"44baf94a"
,"SourceContext":"ArtifactTool.Commands.PipelineArtifactDownloadCommand","UtcTimestamp":"2023-05-04 06:29:14.403Z"}

But we don't know what is it and which url is required for this ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender

Comment: If nobody's got the url answer, I'd suggest running the command on your local and tracing the network traffic using Fiddler/Wireshark.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, if no answer. I have to do that manually :(